# Git fetch on windows waits before starting

Tags: windows, git

I have a git repository that at a beginning works fine (or as good as one can expect on windows), but after 1 week (or so) the repo is getting slower, when I try to run git fetch (and any command using fetch). The terminal freezes for a few minutes and then the fetch begins, the fetch itself is not particularity slow but the wait time makes it a pain.

I have tried:

- Turning of my virus program
- `git config --global core.preloadindex true`
- `git config --global core.fscache true`
- `git config --global gc.auto 256`
- Shutting down all other applications
- Checking out the repository again (works for a few days and then i'ts back).
- `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Anyone have any idea what more I can try, I have tried google but haven't found a solution to my mystery.

Edit (2015-07-02): Added `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` to tested list.

I've run:

```
GIT_TRACE=true git pull
trace: exec: 'git-pull'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'branch.develop.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' 'port' 'user@address' 'git-upload-pack '\''/repo'\''
'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'

#### WAITING for 2 minutes ####

remote: Counting objects: 59063, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (124/124)
...
```

I've marked where the waiting time is.

Comment: Have you tried `git gc`?

Comment: Try this: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`. It will clean and pack all your loose files. !!!! Warning - it might delete un-commited content

Comment: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` does not help.

Comment: Maybe try setting the various [GIT_TRACE* variables](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging) and inspect the additional output?

Comment: I've run
GIT_TRACE=true git pull updated question with respons.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is between the `git pull` execution (on the client) and the remote message from the server saying `remote: counting objects` then it is fragmentation on the server side that you need to address.

Run `git gc --aggessive` to pack the remote repository to one or a few packfiles on the git server that you are pulling from. These will be loaded more efficiently than a selection of objects, and that in turn is likely to affect how quickly the fetch process works.

It's also possible that the machine you're running the remote server on has some kind of anti-virus scanner that's hitting each file that the Git server is loading; the more files you have (and more fragmentation) the greater the problem will be.

Edit: Updated answer to indicate where git gc needs to run, since the fragmented repository is the one that's being pulled from, not pulled to.

Comment: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` does not help.

Comment: How comes that the repo works fine for a while after I do a fresh checkout if the problem is on the server? 

I do not have the administrative right to run the command on the server, I know that the server does not run an antivirus program.